# Is it possible to remote control via USB a Sony DSC HX-200V?

Tags: software, sony, remote, tethering, usb

I was wondering if there is a way to programmatically control a Sony DSC HX-200V camera via its USB port. I tried to find anything on Internet (Google, that is :)) but there seems to be nothing.

I do not have high hopes but StackExchange has never failed to give an answer :)

Comment: what do you mean *programmatically control* ?

Comment: what I mean by _"programmatically control"_ is to be able to use a program / script on a PC (Windows / Linux) which would trigger via the USB port actions on the camera (take a picture for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called **tethering**

This function can be developed in a software if the camera manufacturer allows the use of its firmware (like opening-up the source code), in this model **NOT**. Even the [new Adobe Lightroom does not support it](http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2012/10/lightroom-4-2-now-available.html). So you have to everything manually.

Comment: The camera software does not need to be open source - one can develop alternate firmware like [CHDK for Canon cameras](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK). Since apparently there is neither such firmware for Sony, nor the original one permits to tether the camera I will close the subject (thanks for the answer)